# DB2 select multi rows into one row

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have the following:

```
UserID | Number
1 | 100
1 | 200
1 | 300
2 | 20
2 | 21
2 | 22
3 | 333
......
.....
1000| 23
.......

and I want to get the following result:
UserID | Average
1 | 200
2 | 21
3 | 300
......
......
1000 | 200
......
```

The values are just to get an idea about what i'm talking about!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, AVG(Number) AS Average
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AVG` aggregate:

```
SELECT UserId, AVG(Number)
FROM YourTable
GROUP By UserId
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45bd3/1)